# Reputation Graph Area Selection not Working in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation-graph

The ability to view a reputation graph for a specific time frame is no longer working in Chrome:

[image: SO Reputation Graph]

A user is supposed to be able to select a specific time frame for viewing in the large graph by clicking in the small overview and dragging the blue box to cover the desired time frame. Adjusting the blue box no longer has any effect on what is shown in the large, detailed graph.

I have reproduced this behavior across multiple Stack Exchange accounts. I am using Chrome 49.0.2623.110. The graphs work corerctly in IE 11.0.9600.18125.

Here is a .gif animation of me clicking around in the overview graph without the large graph updating:

[image: Rep graph bug]

Comment: Your screenshot disproves that though'

Comment: @PythonMaster How so? The blue box on the right is what is currently shown in the large graph, and the blue box on the left is the new one. Clicking after creating the second box usually makes the old box disappear (the one on the right), and causes the new box to be shown in detail on the large graph. Currently, clicking after creating a new box does nothing. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I an using Chrome

Comment: If you're using the same version, then I don't know what to make of it. But I still don't think the screenshot "disproves" it though. Admittedly I can't get a great screenshot of something that *isn't* happening, because the old box on the right never disappears.

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all, Chrome 49.0.2623.110

Comment: Might be some user script you installed, they tend to add cool features, while breaking other things. Also check the console of Chrome to see if you get any errors.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i don't have any user scripts installed. The only extensions I have are AdBlock Plus and Google Docs, Slides, and Sheets. Disabling AdBlock had no effect. The console didn't show any messages while I reproduced this. Any other ideas or suggestions?

Comment: @Oded Thanks for looking into it. Can you think of any other backing libraries or software packages that could be different between our systems? I don't know anything about web development, so I don't know what other version numbers or system information could be helpful.

Comment: Difficult one - it could be plugins/add-ons/extensions on your Chrome that are causing the problem (disable them all and see if that helps), could be a badly cached JS file on a proxy or on your browser (Ctrl+F5 tends to help with that one).

Comment: @Oded I disabled all plugins through chrom://plugins/, opened a new browser, confirmed they were still disabled, then did CTRL+F5 on the reputation page and the erroneous behavior was still present. This certainly isn't a show-stopping issue, so I'm fine with dropping it for now (I'm sure you have bigger issues to deal with). Otherwise, I'd be happy to try any other debug steps you think would be helpful.

Comment: @Oded I'm also on a corporate network, so there is definitely a local proxy between me and the internet. I'm also on a system managed by my IT department, so it's possible they have other things running in the background that I'm unaware of. Although I suspect they are unrelated since IE works fine, and since I got some upvotes on this post, I assume (perhaps naively) that others have reproduced it as well.

Comment: Can you make a GIF animation or even a video of the problem? There are probably Chrome extensions to take such GIF or video, if you don't find I'll try to have a look and recommend something. As for upvotes, it's just people who believe you and for properly reporting what appears to be a bug, they don't mean others actually reproduced it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I found a gif creator that let me capture the behavior I'm seeing. I've added it to the post.

Comment: |Really weird. One last idea, try browsing directly to http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/highcharts.js?v=47c74ab4650f - what do you see?

Comment: @ShadowWizard A boatload of text that looks like code. Is there something in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: That's the code responsible for the graph. Hmm.... do you browse https version of the site? (i.e. what is the exact address of the page with the problem?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am not using HTTPS. Just plain ol' http. The MSE address is this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/273585/skrrgwasme?tab=reputation, but I have seen it across all of my SE accounts.

Comment: In case you missed the notification, I created a chat room, where it's more comfortable to guess things: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/998/room-for-shadow-wizard-and-skrrgwasme :)

Comment: I am still having this issue with Chrome `Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)` no highlighting at all

Comment: @Oded any chance to check again, using data from comments and new answers here? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Now that I am using `Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)`  I am able to use this functionality.

Either something was fixed in Chrome or something was fixed in the code.

---

I am still having this issue with Chrome `Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit)` no highlighting at all

here are the only errors that I am getting from the console

> Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts
>   a shadow root is deprecated. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more
>   details. init @ include.preload.js:465

other than that there is no highlighting at all.

I also tried to substitute both `http://` and `https://` at the beginning of the URL and it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, I experience this in Chrome on my work laptop (HP ZBook G2).

I say "oddly" because if I have my Chrome browser open on my laptops screen, the dragging on the graph does not work.  If I move my browser to the external display that is attached across a VGA connection, it *does* work.

IE and Edge experience no issues with this on either screen for my setup.

I should also point out that unlike what the question illustrates in it's gif, the grey highlight does not appear at all for me on drag.  Nothing happens at all.

My Chrome is version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit).  I don't see any errors in my console either.

Comment: I am at the same version now, and I can use it no problem

Comment: [Does your laptop have a touchscreen?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279173/164356)

Comment: @Floern no it doesn't.

Comment: Or maybe Chrome thinks it does, could explain why it works on the VGA monitor but not on the laptop screen itself.

Comment: @Floern good point. I don't know how I could check for this though, if possible.