# Reputation graph not interactable with a touch screen

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

The reputation graph has been broken for years:

[image]

Dragging over the area below will not do anything. Clicking/hovering the bars will also not trigger a popup.

It used to work but since several years ago it stopped working for me. From the comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322492/any-plans-with-the-stack-overflow-theme/322497?noredirect=1#comment342353_322497) I have realized it is working for other users but not me. Therefore I have taken a look at it and I found out that since the page probably thinks I am on a mobile device (I have a touchscreen on Windows 8.1) it is only listening for touch events. (Based on my experience, the code/underlying library must has been written before touchscreen PC's became popular.)

I tested it and indeed, the touch events work. This also explains why it stopped working years ago because I have switched to a laptop with touchscreen.

Another user seems to have a [similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277820/reputation-graph-area-selection-not-working-in-chrome) but they couldn't figure out why. I am not able to confirm that the problem he was experiencing is also related to touchscreens.

Chrome 51, Windows 8.1.

Comment: This issue is a bug in highcharts:  https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6457#issuecomment-290403538.  The bug should be fixed in a recent release.

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce this **only** in Chrome. On my Windows 10 touch-capable laptop, click-and-drag with the mouse works fine in IE and Edge (didn't bother trying in Firefox, Opera, etc.). And in Chrome, it's worse than described above: click-and-drag doesn't even select anything on the lower timeline, never mind get as far as the upper timeline not refreshing to match the selection.

Comment: Why does this question become so popular all in a sudden?