# Reputation graph on profile page is un-draggable

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-graph, graphs

Reputation graph on profile page is un-draggable. Currently displaying data only for last 30 days.

Observed on Google chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) (OS - Win 10)
[image]

Can this be something related to touch based screens?

Note: Not duplicate of [this Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279173/reputation-graph-not-interactable-with-a-touch-screen) as graph is not draggable at all. While in the [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279173/reputation-graph-not-interactable-with-a-touch-screen), graph timeline can selected by dragging pointer in the lower chart but the same is not reflected in the upper chart/graph