# The reputation chart "master-graph" doesn't work on Chrome, but it works on Firefox

Tags: bug, reputation-graph

Go to the page https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899628/stenci?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2017-04-25%2013:18:26Z, and select an area on the chart and nothing happens on Chrome, while it works on Firefox.

I am using Chrome Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit), 100% zoom factor.

Comment: Are you zoomed in/out at all?

Comment: just in case it matters - what chrome version?

Comment: Hm, it works for me on Chrome 58, Windows. Same version (58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)). Is it possible you have some user script or extension that is interfering? Try doing it through an incognito tab (where all extensions are disabled).

Comment: Btw there appear to have been other no repro [reports like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277820/230261) in the past. Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console. The problem seems to be the same as the one described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277820/reputation-graph-area-selection-not-working-in-chrome)